# creating a new crudmodule in meanjs

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, meanjs

I tried to install a new crud module in my mean application with `yo meanjs:crud-module xxxx` command but it resulted in a error saying

> Error meanjs:crud-module rules 
>   You don't seem to have a generator with the name meanjs:crud-module installed.
>   You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].

I have also tried yo meanjs:vertical-module xxxx. it results the same how to resolve it

Comment: my mean version is 0.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the names crud-module and vertical module are no longer used it has to be

```
yo meanjs:mean-module xxxx
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meanjs/l7OvgRrBfuI